# How to configure an openvpn in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

So this is my first time asking a question on here or any forum. I've tried looking into this problem but none of the questions asked or the solutions to those questions really applied to my problem. ill try to be as specific as i can. I'm new to Linux, I've dual booted ubuntu 16.04 on my 64bit laptop. I'm trying to create and configure an openvpn and in trying to `unzip "server.conf.gz"` i run into this

> bash: /etc/openvpn/server.confg: Permission denied

and don't know why. Please if anyone knows what i have to do please help me out, i would really appreciate it. Thank you for taking the time to read through all that.

Comment: What instruction do you use to configure openvpn?

Comment: im sorry i dont understand your question zombic

Comment: Do you use any manual for installing openvpn? :) [this is my bad english]

Comment: kind of, i watch this channel on youtube and they are a reliable source but i ran into this problem which they did not. @zombic

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sudo` before the command or `root` user to execute that command. Your current user doesn't have permission to write in `/etc/openvpn` directory.

Comment: i tried putting sudo and same result, how to i use root?

Comment: @al3x983 Did you run `sudo unzip "server.conf.gz"`?

Comment: not necessarily, i did "gunzip -c server.conf.gz > /etc/openvpn/server.conf" and then tried "sudo gunzip -c server.conf.gz > /etc/openvpn/server.conf" same result didnt even ask me to put in my password @zombic

Comment: Try to use `sudo bash -c 'gunzip -c server.conf.gz > /etc/openvpn/server.conf'`

Comment: Write `sudo su`, enter your root password, execute `gunzip -c server.conf.gz > /etc/openvpn/server.conf` and then write `exit` to go back to your user shell.

Comment: You're welcome @al3x983 . Please, validate the answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Please use:

```
gunzip server.conf.gz -c /etc/openvpn
```

or

```
sudo gunzip server.conf.gz -c /etc/openvpn
```

hope it will works.